# Compare files in two folders using Python

Tags: python, csv, compare, difference

I'm trying to compare all the file-pairs (files with same file name) in two folders 'test1' and 'test2' and print any differences they might have. I have this code below which works partly fine. It gets the files with same file names but compares only the first file-pair and not all the files in the folder. How do I fix it? Sample csv files could be like below

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

def relative_files(path):
    for root, dirnames, files in os.walk(path):
        relroot = os.path.relpath(root, path)
        for filename in files:
            yield os.path.join(relroot, filename)

def difference_in_files (root_one, root_two):
    files_one = set(relative_files(root_one))
    for same in files_one.intersection(relative_files(root_two)):
        try:
            with open(os.path.join(root_one, same)) as csvfile, open(os.path.join(root_two, same)) as csvfile2:
                d = defaultdict(list)
                d2 = defaultdict(list)
                header = next(csvfile).rstrip().split("\t")
                h1 = next((i for i, x in enumerate(header) if x == "h1"),None)
                h2 = next((i for i, x in enumerate(header) if x == "h2"),None)
                header2 = next(csvfile2).rstrip().split("\t")
                h12 = next((i for i, x in enumerate(header2) if x == "h1"),None)
                h22 = next((i for i, x in enumerate(header2) if x == "h2"),None)
                if h1 is not None and h2 is not None:
                    r = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter="\t")
                    for row in r:
                        d[row[h1]].append(row[h2])
                if h12 is not None and h22 is not None:
                    r = csv.reader(csvfile2,delimiter="\t")
                    for row in r:
                        d2[row[h12]].append(row[h22])
            d2 = {k: list(set(v)) for k,v in dict(d2).items()}
            d = {k: list(set(v)) for k,v in dict(d).items()}

            diff = dict([ (key, d2.get(key, d.get(key))) for key in set(d.keys()+d2.keys()) if (key in d and (not key in d2 or d2[key] != d[key])) or (key in d2 and (not key in d or d[key] != d2[key])) ])
            diff2 = dict([ (key, d.get(key, d2.get(key))) for key in set(d2.keys()+d.keys()) if (key in d2 and (not key in d or d[key] != d2[key])) or (key in d and (not key in d2 or d2[key] != d[key])) ])
            return diff, diff2
        except TypeError:
            pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root_one = 'test1'
    root_two = 'test2'
    difference_in_files (root_one, root_two)
```

test1/csv1.csv

```
h1,h2,h3
aa,90,io
bb,86,0n
```

test1.csv2.csv

```
h1,h8,h2
jj,kj,64
df,hj,12
```

test2/csv1.csv

```
h1,h2,h3
aa,90,io
bb,66,0n
```

test2.csv2.csv

```
h1,h8,h2
jj,kj,64
df,hj,12
mm,h9,09
```

It compares only csv1 from both the files and not csv2.

Comment: I think that the reason is that `return diff, diff2` is in the for loop. It will execute at the end of the first iteration of the loop. Thus no other iterations will be executed.

Comment: @Marcin Outside for loop prints `None`.

Comment: just check if this return is actually always returning after the first iteration.maybe its not the problem at all. just my guess.

Comment: @Marcin is right.  Instead of `return`ing the value, you probably should `yield` it.  Then your *function* is transformed into a *generator*, and the caller can use it like this:  `for diff1, diff2 in difference_in_files(root_one, root_two): print diff1, diff2`.

Comment: Or, if you want to have a `list` of the values, just call `list(difference_in_files(root_one, root_two))`.

Comment: @dan no worries. glad I could help. I will make an answer, so that ppl now the question has an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So just to make an official answer. the issue was that:

> return diff, diff2 is in the for loop. It will be executed at the end of
>   the first iteration of the loop. Thus no other iterations will be
>   executed.